# Suppose X is a random variable with cdf F(x) and Y=aX+b , What is the cdf of Y in terms of F?

Tags: probability

Suppose X is  a  random  variable  with  cdf F(x)  and  denote  a  new  random  variable $Y=aX+b$ where $a >0$ and $b∈R$.
What is the cdf of Y in terms of F?

My attempt;

I know $F(X)=P(X≤ x)$

so $F(Y)=(aX+b ≤ x)$

Is there more to it?

Comment: $$F_Y(y)=\mathsf P(aX+b\le y)=\mathsf P\left(X\le\frac{y-b}a\right)=F_X\left(\frac{y-b}a\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Y \leq y)=P(aX+b \leq y)=P(X \leq \frac {y-b} a) =F(\frac {y-b} a)$.